# How do i force a resolution on a screen that doesn't support it

Tags: resolution

Is it possible to force your computer/monitor to display a higher resolution then what's supported by the monitor? I have a 1366x768 monitor and i want 1080p at the very least. Is it possible for me to get 1080p? What do i have to do? I have a intel uhd gpu and intel pentium cpu.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: You can set a custom resolution that is too large, but part of your screen will "fall off" the monitor.

Comment: @harrymc More often screens will just reject the input and displays nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This is (sadly) not possible. The maximum resolution of a display is determined by the amount of physical pixels on your display panel (-> the size of your pixels in relation to your display size).

It only works the other way around:
Simply put, by "grouping" adjacent pixels together, the GPU can "create bigger pixels", reducing the perceived resolution.

You could theoretically set a higher resolution than reccomended, which would lead to a "zoom-like" effect, since the screen can only display a part of the pixel range that it should, effectively ruining your user experience entirely (have fun setting it back to normal, depending on how you did it)